# How to get Current viewcontroller (currently Presenting) using storyboard id in swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

**How to get the presenting view controller in swift. I am using storyboard id.**And for presenting next viewcontroller how can I add to the hierarchy?

I tried like this:

```
   let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let logincontroller  = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController.presentingViewController == logincontroller {

     let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let nextVC  = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storayboardIdentifier)

     self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

     }
```

In Appdelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

         if isLoggedin == false {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController


        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
    else {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
 }

}
```

The code works, it display the view but it still have a warning

> Failed to instantiate the default view controller for
>   UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is
>   not set?

Answer (score 1):

Check initial entry points.

Also to present screen below code practice is better way.

```
let objNextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_NextViewController") as? ViewController

self.presentViewController(objNextViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
            print("Achive")
}
```

[image]

**EDITED :**

If you want to present viewcontroller from already presented view controller then use below code.

```
var currentViewController : UIViewController!


let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

if let viewControllers = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController 
{

    self.currentViewController = viewControllers as UIViewController

}
else if let viewControllers = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers 
{

    self.currentViewController = viewControllers.last! as UIViewController

}


let objNewViewController : NewViewController!

    self.currentViewController.presentViewController(objNewViewController!, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                        NSLog("Achived")

})
```

Comment: That won't quite compile.  `presentViewController` doesn't accept optionals but `objNextViewController` would be an optional here.  Also, you probably want `as? UIViewController` (although the cast is unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroOrnano

Comment: my intial  viewcontroller define on appdelegate depend on conditions,then how i can set it on stor board attribute insepector.

Comment: And also my question includes how to get currently presenting viewcontroller using storyboard id

Comment: You can set entry point to Navigation Controller, through condition in appdelegate you can set root view controller to navigation controller. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for `presentingViewController`using storyboard name:

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController

self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : WelcomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeID") as WelcomeViewController    
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) 
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't set an initial view controller for your storyboard.

To fix this open your storyboard and select the `UIViewController` you want to display as the first one. Then in the `Attributes inspector` tab(third one from the right in the utilities panel), look under the `View Controller` section and make sure the `Is Initial View Controller` checkbox is checked.